# Setting a property on a Laravel Model

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I need to set property on a laravel model using chained methods and I am wondering how to do it the correct way, because right now the model does not get the value as it should.

I have a main database called Portal and then there are two additional databases called Europe and Africa (Unfortunately, due to other applications I cannot migrate the databases into one). The Europe and Africa database have the same structure.

Inside the Portal database I have a database table called Servers, this database table contains an IP address of a Linux server and a database connection name, Europe or Africa.

First, I am getting the database connection from the Portal -> Servers table.

```
$connection = Servers::where('id', $id)->first()->data_connection;
```

Next, I am fetching Jobs from Portal -> Jobs table like:

```
Return Jobs::filter($filter)
->Connection($connection)
->where("server_id", "=", $id)
->with("origination_log")
->get();
```

The origination_log data either comes from the Europe database or Africa depending on the Server database record.

The Jobs model looks as followed:

```
class Jobs extends Model
{
    public $data_connection = "Europe";

    public function scopeConnection($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['data_connection'] = $value;
    }

    public function origination_log()
    {
        return $this->setConnection($this->attributes['data_connection'])
            ->hasOne('Models\OriginationLog', 'id', 'log_id');
    }
}
```

So the idea behind this all… is fetch database name… present it to the Jobs model as a parameter… then call origination_log method on the model which creates a database connection using the database name… (database is obvious setup in the config file).

However the above solution does not work… because the method origination_log does not have the data_connection string even though it was retrieved with $connection and provided to the model.

The OriginationLog is very simple...

```
class OriginationLog extends Model
{
  public $timestamps = false;

  protected $table = "log";

  public $connection = "Europe";
}
```

Comment: I think you need to clarify what you try to achieve. Your example seems a bit confusing (to me). So I can only guess that you might be looking for appends? https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-serialization#appending-values-to-json

Comment: you can use pipelines.

Comment: @Frnak thanks for your feedback, I have updated the question with additional information, hope it clears things up...

Answer (score 0):

```
class JobsModel extends Model
{
    public const $something = "ABC";

    public function scopeDoSomething($value)
    {
        $this->attributes[self::something] = $value;
    }
}

JobsModel::filter($filter)
    ->DoSomething("Lorem Ipsum")
    ->get();
```

Comment: Unfortunately this throws an error: 

{
  "message": "syntax error, unexpected '$something ' (T_VARIABLE)",
  "exception": "ParseError",
....